# How does the PATH variable look to an application?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I understand that the system and user PATH variables are appended to each other and are seen as a single PATH variable by applications.

However, some applications might alter the PATH variable before starting.
How can I see how the PATH variable looks to an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask an application to show it. Most CLI shells and programming language REPLs have this feature:

- Run `set PATH` or even `set P` within Command Prompt.
- Run `gci env:PATH` within PowerShell.
- Run `os.environ["PATH"]` within Python.
- Run `echo getenv("PATH")` or `echo $_ENV["PATH"]` within PHP.

You can also use tools such as ProcExp or Process Hacker (both of which are Task Manager replacements); they can show various information about a process including its environment block.

*(Note that `set` within Cmd isn't 100% complete; there are special environment variables like `=C:` that it deliberately does not show.)*

Comment: Thanks, I'm specifically interested for an application that does not have a console. You mention Process Explorer and an `environment block`. Could you perhaps elaborate on that? It seems that that might be the solution.

Comment: Just start a command prompt from your programs' File - Open dialog and type `set`. Programs inherit from the program that starts them.

Comment: You do that by right clicking CMD.exe in File Open (or Save As) and choosing Open instead of Select.

Answer (score 1):

This program lists the class of each variable. Programs only see the process. Programs query for specific variables. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable

Output of https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/listenvironmentexe-list-system-user.html List System, User, Volatile, and the resultant Process environmental variables that programs use.

```
--------
System
--------
ComSpec=%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
Link=/pdb:none /MAPINFO:LINES
...

--------
Volatile - These are set at logon
--------
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-UCDGI39
USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-UCDGI39
...

--------
User - These override system variables, and in the case of PATH are added to the system PATH
--------
include=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\atl\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\mfc\include
;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\include
lib=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\mfc\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\lib
...

--------
Process - This is the combined environment from the above for the program
          Variables starting with an equals sign, such as =C:=C:\Windows are internal CMD variables
          CMD simulates a default directory per drive like MSDos. This is how it keeps track
--------
=C:=C:\Windows\System32
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\David Candy\AppData\Roaming
...

--------
Dynamic - These are updated each time they are used
--------
CD
DATE
TIME
RANDOM
...
```